# Grouping Classes & Subclasses in saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to create a saved search that sums total sales by the parent class. I'm trying a CASE statement but can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have:

```
CASE
WHEN {class} LIKE 'B2B%’ THEN 'B2B' 
WHEN {class} LIKE 'Amazon%’ THEN 'Amazon'
WHEN {class} LIKE 'Website%’ THEN ' B2C'
ELSE ‘’
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but that format never works for me either, although Netsuite documentation suggests that it should/does.  Try nested CASE statements.

```
CASE WHEN {class} LIKE 'B2B' THEN 'B2B' ELSE 
 CASE WHEN {class} LIKE 'Amazon%' THEN 'Amazon' ELSE 
  CASE WHEN {class} LIKE 'Website%' THEN ' B2C' ELSE '' END 
 END 
END
```

Or you can use SUBSTR({class},0,INSTR({class},':')-2) to get just the part of the string before " :", assuming all of your classes have these characters present.

Once you have that column formula working, group results based on this formula, add total sales as a column and group that but select "Sum".

Comment: There's an extra ")" at the end of your suggested formula, but otherwise that works great!